# what is the benefit of using callback function vs just inserting the function inside the function

Tags: javascript, callback

I been reading about callBack function, and are trying to use it. But I don't see the benefit of it. Take my codes below as an example, I don't see the difference between #1 and #2. Rather #1 seem so pointless

## 1:

```
function serverConnect(callback){
//Connecting to server
var xmlhttp;
var getString;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var url="server/topHouses.php";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        //Storing response from server, an array encoded by json    
        getString = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
        callback(getString);

    }
}

xmlhttp.send(); 
}

function doStuff(string){
//do stuff
}

serverConnect(doStuff);
```

## 2:

```
function serverConnect(){
//skip skip skip
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    //Storing response from server, an array encoded by json    
    getString = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
    doStuff(getString);

}
}

function doStuff(string){
//do stuff
}

serverConnect();
```

Comment: #2 doesn't make any sense. `serverConnect` doesn't accept any parameters but the call is trying to pass in the function.

Comment: @Spencer sorry that was a mistake, I edited it just now

Comment: #2 is fine if `serverConnect` only `doesStuff`; you're basically hardcoding the callback. But what if you want to do something different given a condition? That's when dynamic callback is useful.

Comment: In javacript function declaration save state of the all variables and function with the same block level. the callback function execute using those variables and can access them. it's called closures. read about it on google `javsctipt closure`

Comment: @Dvir, that's not quite how closures work. The callback knows nothing about its execution environment, any local variable that you want to use inside the callback must be passed explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example there isn't really much of a benefit, at least from what I can see. Here's where a callback method as a parameter can be useful.

```
myFunction(successCallback)
{
    var url="server/topHouses.php";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            if(!successCallback)
                // Some default behavior
            else
                successCallback($.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText));
        }
    };
}
```

By allowing you, or some other developer to override the success behavior it gives your application greater flexibility without sacrificing the convenience of letting the method handle things in a standardized way.

Incidentally, if you're using jQuery (as indicated by your `$.parseJSON` call) why are you using `xmlhttp` instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: yea I am in the process of changing my codes to jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is reusability. Let's take a simplified example. #1 with callback allows you to do this:

```
function handleStatusResponse () {}
function handleUpdateStatusResponse () {}
function handleEmailResponse () {}

function serverConnect (query,callback) {

    // ajax stuff here

    callback(data)
}

serverConnect('GET_STATUS',handleStatusResponse );
serverConnect('UPDATE_STATUS',handleUpdateStatusResponse );
serverConnect('SEND_EMAIL',handleEmailResponse );
```

vs #2 without callback which would require you to do this:

```
function handleStatusResponse () {}
function handleUpdateStatusResponse () {}
function handleEmailResponse () {}

function serverConnectGetStatus (callback) {

    // ajax stuff here

    handleStatusResponse (data)
}

function serverConnectUpdateStatus (callback) {

    // ajax stuff here

    handleUpdateStatusResponse (data)
}

function serverConnectSendEmail (callback) {

    // ajax stuff here

    handleEmailResponse (data)
}

serverConnectGetStatus ();
serverConnectUpdateStatus();
serverConnectSendEmail();
```

While both methods encapsulate the operation #2 has lots of duplicated ajax code. Callbacks is to program flow what function arguments is to variables - they allow you to generalize your algorithm.